# Why am I getting this error with Asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm getting this error after my code runs for a few minutes:
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<timer() done, defined at c:\Users(my name)\Desktop\DiscordBot\roblox test copy.py:12> exception=KeyError('data')>
I'm pretty new to python so I can't get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
from time import sleep
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import asyncio
import requests
import json
import time


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

async def timer():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    channel = bot.get_channel(my discord channel, not sending in case it can be traced to my server)
    msg_sent = False

    while True:
        r = requests.get('https://badges.roblox.com/v1/users/2642375267/badges?limit=10&sortOrder=Desc')
        badgedata = r.json()['data']
        risetimes = []

        for d in badgedata:
            badgeid = d['id']
            risetimes.append(badgeid)

        firstThing = risetimes[0]

        times = []

        for rt in risetimes:
            eztime = (str(rt))
            times.append(eztime)

        xd = requests.get('https://badges.roblox.com/v1/users/2642375267/badges/awarded-dates?badgeIds=' + str(firstThing))
        badgegaineddata = xd.json()['data']
        badgegainedtime = []
        for ig in badgegaineddata:
            badgegaineduwu = ig['awardedDate']
            badgegainedtime.append(badgegaineduwu)

        firstElement = badgegainedtime[0]
        date_string = str(firstElement)
        Thedatetime = date_string
        date_string = date_string[:26]
        date_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
        unix_time = datetime.datetime.timestamp(date_format)
        unix_time = unix_time - 18000

        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time)
        currentunixtime = time.time()
        if unix_time > currentunixtime -3:
            await channel.send("https://www.roblox.com/badges/" + str(firstThing))
            await channel.send(dt)
            msg_sent = True
            sleep(3)

    await asyncio.sleep(1)

bot.loop.create_task(timer())
bot.run('token')
```

Comment: r.json()['data'] - you have no 'data' key in response. Print it out: `print(r.json())`


You should use aiohttp to make http requests asynchronously.

Comment: What do you mean? I printed that out and when I got the error there was 'data' in the latest thing that was printed.

Comment: The exception says that there is no 'data' key at line 12 in `roblox test copy.py`.